# Firefox cannot make an instance of class generated with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, typescript

I have a simple class for wrapping a Grid control which I have placed within a module named Components and when I test it in Firefox 14.0.1 I'm getting:

TypeError: Components.Grid is not a constructor @http://...

Here the code generated by TypeScript:

```
var Components;
(function (Components) {
    Components.gridDefaults = {
        datatype: "json",
        autowidth: true,
        rowNum: 30,
        rowList: [
            10, 
            20, 
            30
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        pager: "#grid-pager"
    };
    var Grid = (function () {
        function Grid(selector, options) {
            var opts = Components.gridDefaults;
            if(options !== undefined && options !== null) {
                $.extend(opts, options);
            }
            this.grid = $(selector).jqGrid(opts);
        }
        Grid.prototype.setToolbar = function (options) {
            var pager = this.grid.getGridParam().pager;
            if(pager !== undefined && pager !== null) {
                this.grid.navGrid(pager, options);
            }
            return this;
        };
        Grid.prototype.jqGrid = function () {
            return this.grid;
        };
        Grid.prototype.filter = function (criteria) {
            this.grid.setGridParam({
                page: 1,
                postData: criteria
            });
            this.reload();
        };
        Grid.prototype.reload = function () {
            this.grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        };
        return Grid;
    })();
    Components.Grid = Grid;    
})(Components || (Components = {}));

//@ sourceMappingURL=grid-component.js.map
```

and here the line where Firefox is complaining about the lack of a constructor:

```
var grid = new Components.Grid("#grid-container", {
            url: "/Home/Data",
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
                { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, jsonmap: "invdate" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name asc, invdate', width: 100 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right" },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                id: "id",
                repeatitems: false
            }
        });
```

<strike>I would like to hear from someone @TypeScript team.</strike>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not on the TypeScript team, nor have I ever used it.  But this is not a TypeScript problem, I believe.  The problem is that you're trying to overwrite something that Firefox is including as a native, namely `Components`.

If you changed to

```
var Comps;
(function (Components) {  // keep the local name or change to Comps, as you like
    Components.gridDefaults = {
    // ... 
})(Comps || (Comps = {}));
var grid = new Comps.Grid("#grid-container", { /* ... */ });
```

I think it will work better.

I assume this means changing your Typescript module name.  But I don't know anything about that.

Comment: +1 - Components is really a reserved word as far as Firefox is concerned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.utils.import

Comment: Scott, thanks for taking me out of another silly moment...
You nailed it!!